# Creating a linked server connection to NetSuite

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, netsuite

I'm trying to access `NetSuite's` data from SQL Server as the NetSuite reporting by itself isn't enough. For doing so, I installed the `NetSuite ODBC adapter` on the server and tried creating a `linked server` connection from `SQL Server` in order to be able to access data from `NetSuite`.

The problem that I'm facing now is that the `NetSuite Adapter` isn't available in the list of `linked server` connections.

Would anyone please be able to let me know how to configure the `NetSuite adapter` so that the data may be imported in `SQL Server` using SQL queries?

Comment: Are you sure about the fact we can do SQL query directly on NetSuite ? I've been looked for that since a long time, but didn't find how to do so.

At least, you should go and check different way to deal with your NetSuite's data with SuiteScript and their API. Link to the doc : https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=5732122&c=NLCORP&h=5fca4bf5dd825a28ab41&_xt=.pdf&addrcountry=US

Answer (score 2):

After installing the ODBC driver for NetSuite, verify that you have a System DSN correctly configured (this should be created for you as part of the install):

- Name: NetSuite_Prod (can be anything you'd like)
- Service Host:  odbcserver.netsuite.com (possibly odbcserver.na1.netsuite.com)
- Service Data Source: NetSuite.com
- Account ID:  (your NetSuite account ID)
- Role ID: (internal ID of the role that you'd like to use, Administrator is 3)

---

When creating your linked server from SSMS:

- Linked Server: NETSUITEPROD
- Other Data source Provider: MS OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
- Product Name: NetSuite.com
- Data Source: NetSuite_Prod (should match your name above)
- Security:  Be made using this security context (enter your NetSuite username and password)

---

Also make sure that you're installing ODBC drivers for the same architecture as your SQL server installation (i.e., 64-bit vs 32-bit)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I somehow don't see a system DSN created for the NetSuite adapter, there is a user DSN though. I followed your steps but the linked server connection wasn't successful. Any tips?

Comment: I tried adding a System DSN and repeated the process, still no luck :(

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about the errors that you might be receiving or what you may be experiencing?  It's difficult to troubleshoot without more information.